# Routinely pull data from remote database to local

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a simpler approach to routinely keep a local MySQL database updated with data from a remote database? My setup needs me to run a local copy of the project in the office network to allow local email sending. But the emails link back to a live server. Also, the admin users need to access the project from the internet anywhere to compose the emails. Currently, my options are:

1. Connect local project to the remote database.
2. Export the remote database, clean the local database and then import the dump.

This is something I need to routinely do every week. I went with approach #1 but it takes a long time to pull data this way. So I am really wondering if I should do this in the long run?

Answer (score 0):

On routine basis, just do the `mysqldump` export on remote server and then on local server do `mysqldup` import or `mysql` import.

```
mysqldump -u root-proot -h remote-server test > db%FileDate%.sql
```

And on local server, do the import

```
mysql -u root-proot -h local-server test < db%FileDate%.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql incremental backup. Please refer below link.

https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtrabackup/10772-[script]-automatic-backups-incremental-full-and-restore

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/8.0/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html